# Lexer rule for a sentence

Tags: antlr, lexer

I know lexer rules are to match words but not the sentence. But is it possible to do it. Because My input has like the following formats

```
ADD FILE first-doc VERSION 1 TYPE sequential FIXED 23 BLOCK 23 MODE 
ebdic LABEL standard KEY REC_NR#09545 RULE DOMANI _ scorebestand MKC
```

and anther input may have like

```
ADD FILE secound-doc VERSION 3 TYPE normal FIXED 39 BLOCK 39 MODE 
gdieds LABEL constant KEY CTR-NR#62872 
RULE CBTPSN49 : dagextract (loadfile) met key PIB_KLN_NR
```

In above both the inputs my parser rule looks like

```
add_file   :
'ADD FILE' file=String 'VERSION' ver=Integer 'TYPE' String 
'FIXED' Integer 'BLOCK' Integer 'MODE' codePage=String
'LABEL' String KEY  key=String ;
```

I was able to write upto the KEY because everything is single word but can't able to proceed further with RULE because it varies with the sentence

Even i tried with greedy match

```
All   : .*;
```

But it is throwing error for me.

Lexer Rules for above statment

```
WhiteSpace: ('\r' | '\t' | '\u000C' | '\n' | ' ') { $channel=HIDDEN; };

COMMENT:('**'.*'\n'|'REMARKS'.*'\n')*{skip();};

String: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'-'|'#') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'-'|'#')*;

Integer: '-'? ('0' | '1'..'9' ('0'..'9')*);
```

My question is "Is it possible to match multiple words with one lexer rule? 
If so how to do that?"

Am i able to achive this only in ANTLR 4? I'm only two weeks old to this ANTLR
please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ANTLR4** *parser* rule below reads everything until the end of the line.

```
add_file   :
'ADD FILE' file=String 'VERSION' ver=Integer 'TYPE' String 
'FIXED' Integer 'BLOCK' Integer 'MODE' codePage=String
'LABEL' String 'KEY'  key=String 'RULE' expr=everything_until_CR '\r'? '\n'?;

everything_until_CR : ~('\n'|'\r')* ;
```

In **ANTLR3**, this unfortunately doesn't seem to work. A workaround *lexer* rule is suggested below. You'd have to strip the leading "RULE" in the target language.

```
RULE : 'RULE ' ~('\n'|'\r')* ;

add_file   :
  'ADD FILE' file=String 'VERSION' ver=Integer 'TYPE' String 
  'FIXED' Integer 'BLOCK' Integer 'MODE' codePage=String
  'LABEL' String 'KEY'  key=String
  expr=RULE '\r'? '\n'? {System.out.println($expr.text.substring(5));}
;
```

If you really need context-sensitive *lexer* rules, have a look at [island grammars](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Island+Grammars+Under+Parser+Control) (link to ANTLR3 doc). 'Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Marc Q.

    `everything_until_CR : ~('\n')+ ;`   is not working in my case

Comment: Hi Mahes! Was my assumption about ANTLR3 right ? What is your reason for not using ANTLR4 ?

Comment: Yeah I'm using ANTLR 3 only. I don't have Eclipse 4 for intalling Antlr 4 Eclipse plugin. Eventhough I tried to generate lexer and parser using build.xml. But the syntax differs from ANTLR 3 to ANTLR 4 and ANTLR 4 is not taking rewrite rule. Since I have very less time I continued to use ANTLR 3

Comment: @Mahes Added a "solution" for ANTLR3.

Comment: Hi @Marc Q. My File has rewrite rule like this  `^( XML_ELEMENT["SOURCE"] ^(XML_ATTRIBUTE["BUSINESSNAME"]) ^(XML_ATTRIBUTE["DATABASETYPE"] CONSTANT["FLAT FILE"])
        ^(XML_ATTRIBUTE["DBDNAME"] CONSTANT["FLAT_FILE"])
        ^(XML_ATTRIBUTE["DESCRIPTION"])
        ^(XML_ATTRIBUTE["NAME"] $file) ^(XML_ATTRIBUTE["OBJECTVERSION"] CONSTANT["1"]) ^(XML_ATTRIBUTE["OWNERNAME"]) ^(XML_ATTRIBUTE["VERSIONNUMBER"] $ver]) `  I think the presence of rewrite rule is making problem. Because in Interpreter it is generating the tree for your **solution**. But it is not generating required XML as expected.

Comment: @Mahes Your original question was _"Is it possible to match multiple words with one lexer rule?"_. Maybe you should close this question and formulate a new one, with the appropriate subject and including all relevant code snippets and error messages if any.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another way to parse a Sentence just by adding `String*` at the end. Please have a look at my grammar below and It seams to work well

`add_file   :
   'ADD FILE' file=String 'VERSION' ver=Integer 'TYPE' String 
   'FIXED' Integer 'BLOCK' Integer 'MODE' codePage=String
   'LABEL' String 'KEY'  key=String 'RULE' String*;`

//Lexer Rule for String

`String: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'-'|'#'|':') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'-'|'#'|':')*;`